# Image Container Drag'N'Drop no overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop

I would like to make a Div Container, where a user can add Boxes (also divs) wich can be dragged arround, but don't overlap. So i started with the container:

```
<div id="image_container"></div>
```

I want to change the images afterwards. So The width is always given, for example 800px, but the hight should be auto. I tried following:

```
div#image_container{
    position: relative;
    background: url('http://www.locationscout.net/public/images/2015-02/externsteine-germany_l.jpeg');
    width: 400px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
}
```

But couldn't get a result. How would you do that? Since the whole app will not work without JavaScript, i could adjust the hight with that. What do you think about that? So if the image loads, fire the function wich does that.

After the container is done, the user should be able to add boxes into it. He should be able to input the height and width and add up to 4 boxes, not more. But the size should be adjustable via a slider and stay relative to all other boxer.
So... If there are 2 Boxes, one 400x400 and the other 200x100, he could adjust the sizes with the slider for example to, 200x200/100x50, 800x800/400x100 but even smaller steps like 480x480/240x120. That could be done with this slider:

```
<input type="range" min="0" value="0" max="100" step="1">
```

How would you do that? I would give the formats via a

Then the boxes should be added into the container and they're draggable, but don't overlap. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrAdE/988/) but better code. The one i wrote is just bad. The JS is done with a plugin and isn't efficient. What could you recommend?

Greetings
c144